# Should I use event delegation, to be economical with JS-events at i.e. table cell level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

If I have a table in which I want to react to table-cell events, is it better to put the event on the table-element and handle cell specific events with the help of i.e. `closest("td")`, or is it ok to put the event on the table cell? (I'm talking about tables with a large number of cells, all of which are visible.)

```js
// pseudo react-code
return (
  <table onClick={handleCellClick}>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>
    </tr>
    //...
  </table>
)
```

or

```js
// pseudo react-code
return (
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td onClick={...}>...</td><td onClick={...}>...</td><td onClick={...}>...</td><td onClick={...}>...</td>
    </tr>
    //...
  </table>
)
```

Comment: The first example is called ["event delegation"](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and would be the preferred option. Maybe identify the cells with a data attribute.

Comment: I think it depends on what you want.
I prefer to use event on tr element, but I dont need to know wich cell is clicked.
If you really NEED to know the td element wich was clicked, use the second option.

Comment: But it's not a problem to find out the cell, which was clicked, even if the listener is listening on the `table` or the `tr`. So I think like @Andy, `event delegation` is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusion is that, in vanilla JavaScript, event delegation is the preferred solution, to avoid memory and performance issues. If you are using a JavaScript frontend library like React.js or a framework like Ember, Angular, ... you have to read the docs and check how events are managed. In case of React.js it is unnecessary, to implement custom event delegation, because React.js does this optimisation for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking about React specifically: [No, you don't need to put only a single event handler at the table, React already does event delegation for you](https://dev.to/thawsitt/should-i-use-event-delegation-in-react-nl0). So using `<td onClick={…}>` is probably a lot simpler, especially if you use nested components.

Comment: Huh. Well I learned something new today. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Without really knowing what your click handler is meant to be doing, here's an an example using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/), and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), to show how you can identify individual cells.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('td')) {
      const { dataset: { id } } = e.target;
      console.log(id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <table onClick={handleClick}>
      <tr>
        <td data-id="1-1">1-1</td>
        <td data-id="1-2">1-2</td>
        <td data-id="1-3">1-3</td>
        <td data-id="1-4">1-4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-id="2-1">2-1</td>
        <td data-id="2-2">2-2</td>
        <td data-id="2-3">2-3</td>
        <td data-id="2-4">2-4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; bordeR: 1px solid #565656; }
td { padding: 0.44em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
td:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffff00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```